# orginal broken part from samsung, can't replace with unbroken

Tags: ssd, dvd, laptop-repair

I have samsung NP550P5C laptop and I wanted to replace dvd driver with ssd. I took off dvd drive, and try to put ssd with case. but It doesn't fit. after that It made me wonder why It doesn't fit like half cm. It was the socket. I did examine the difference about two cases and there is funny difference. orginal cases board under the socket/connector is broken to made it fit, so unbroken case doesn't fit. Any suggestion how to fix this?

[image: Orginal Broken DVD]

[image: Replacement SSD]

Comment: There's different thicknesses of drives - but I can't remember off hand what they are. I've seen this with one of my old laptops which had a bigger bay than drive so there was a slight gap

Comment: While the interfaces are standardized to an extent, the thicknesses arn't. I *think* there's 9.5 and 7.5 mm thick drives. You can fit a 7.5 mm drive in a 9.5 bay, but not vice versa. Your caddy is 9.5 mm. Your old drive and bay are 7.5 mm. There's apparently even older 12.5mm drives

Comment: nope, both thickness are same. even orginal one looks 0.5 mm bigger.

Comment: Thats odd. What do you mean by 'broken' then?

Comment: can't you see at first photo? they file a bit of board around socket.

Comment: I do not think you described the exact problem you are having well?  Is it height, width or the connectors lining up?  What is "broken" in the original case?  You could go into much more detail of what you observed in your original question.

Comment: please check two connectors/sockets, can't you see that board is broken under the connector/socket at first photo? that doesn't fit because in the second photo that part isn't broken. I can't understand why I can't explain this?? Its kind of obvious.

Comment: obvious to you. 1st picture Your saying that the PCB that is slotted into the metal case is broken, and the connection area is moved up because of this?  Ahhhh and re-reading the question again, it begins to make sence.  It was broken or got broken and moved up to fit the socket location that it originally was in.    The picture in that area looks very dark on my monitor, cant hardly see in there.  Did you first test the SSD without the adapter case around it?  Then it is just metal holding it in place right?  could you modify the adapter case to move the disk up in it?

Comment: Samsung broke it on purpose to make it fit there(design fault), now I want to change it but It doesn't fit because my replacement is not broken.

Comment: And it would be a bad idea to be (even) bending things around like that on most of this stuff, unless you know where all the connections are and how it could effect it, even then stress could cause things to become unsoldered and all. Someone may have already made a special case that copes with that design. Myself I would just do the best I could at bending metal, making slots out of holes to move the screws , and cutting away stuff that got in the way.  It is just a bracket right?  you might not even need all part of the bracket to get it held well and aligned properly.

Comment: Its not bracket, Its board itself(green), and I can see some onboard connection going-on where I need to cut. It might not work after I cut some part from there, or not I don't know.

Comment: the ssd is mostly just a board like http://images.anandtech.com/reviews/storage/Samsung/SSD830/_DSC2164sm.jpg inside a case, the case unnesssisary to operation. It does not seem logical to alter or cut or bend anything, as it should be able to be connected offset without doing that?